# derive a depth of plate contacting a particle by using a curvature

Tags: approximation, curvature, angle, spherical-geometry

I am learning physics theory called Hertz contact theory which considers a small particle contacting a plate. But I have been stuck in the geometry problem. I would like to get $z$ in the figure. When $z$ is very small, the theory assumes
$$z(r) = R-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\approx r^2/2R, \quad if \quad r<<R$$
$R$ is the radius of curvature. How we can make this approximation?

I'm really happy if you could answer these questions.

[image]

Comment: This is not the equation, but a figure problem. Probably my question was bad and I edited it.

Comment: Do you know that $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+x/2$ for $x\approx 0$? If not, you should.